# Show path from project root in ZSH Prompt

Tags: zsh, prompt

If my pwd is `~/repos/blog/app/views/`, I'd like to show only `blog/app/views` in the prompt i.e. I want to show only the project root. Project root is the parent directory of `.git` directory. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

You can execute arbitrary code to display the prompt if you set the [`prompt_subst`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPTSUBST) option. You don't need to look up the `.git` directory every time a prompt is displayed: in practice, it's enough to update a variable on every current directory change, in the [`chpwd`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-chpwd) hook, and use that variable in your prompt.

```
setopt prompt_subst
chpwd () {
  git_root=$PWD
  while [[ $git_root != / && ! -e $git_root/.git ]]; do
    git_root=$git_root:h
  done
  if [[ $git_root = / ]]; then
    unset git_root
    prompt_short_dir=%~
  else
    prompt_short_dir=${PWD#$git_root/}
  fi
}
chpwd
PS1='${prompt_short_dir}%# '
```

Comment: This is good, but I've found a simpler method: `git rev-parse --show-prefix` to show exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @asattar That's another possibility, yes. I prefer to avoid calling external commands, but if you always work on a reasonably fast machine, that's not a concern.